# WML factor on French's web site

Tags: fama-french

On Prof. French's web site we have the following

http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/f-f_developed.html

> > WML is the equal-weight average of the returns for the two winner portfolios for a region minus the average of the returns for the two loser portfolios,
> >
> > WML = 1/2 (Small High + Big High)
> > – 1/2 (Small Low + Big Low).

Is there a typo here? Shouldn't this be

WML = 1/2 (Small Winner + Big Winner) – 1/2 (Small Loser + Big Loser).

To me High/Low means high/low book to market

Comment: French consistently uses the terms "high/low" instead of "winner/losers" on his website when referring to price momentum. See for example the [momentum factor](http://mba.tuck.dartmouth.edu/pages/faculty/ken.french/Data_Library/det_mom_factor.html). Instead, the value factor, HML, is composed of Small Value, Big Value, Small Growth and Big Growth. So, he doesn't use the terms "high/low" for BE/ME but for momentum. I agree with you that it sounds a bit unusual given what HML and WML stand for.

Comment: Thanks, that's very helpful.